# How many hours it takes to instagram approve the app to get access_token?

Tags: instagram-api

I created the app to get images from instagram with hashtag.
I am trying to change the permission of public_content in my app ( at instagram developer page)
I clicked the button "Start a submission" 2 days ago.
But now current status is `Pending Review`
Does someone know how many hours it takes to get instagram approval?

[image: Here is the capture of status]

Comment: Many people finished it within 24 hours.
But I clicked the submit button 44 hours ago and status still `Pending Review`.

Comment: It depends on your app and Instagram. My app took more than 24 hours to get reviewed.

Answer (score 2):

It is taking me 3days + for instagram. Still pending

Comment: Its more than 9 days for me now .. wth?

Comment: I got approved in August (applied in apr), Good luck bro

Answer (score 1):

i have had anything from 12hrs - 2 days

Answer (score 1):

Normally, It takes 24 hours. Additional, Instagram doesn't support at weekend and you should also notice the difference of timezone. Once, i have to wait up to 3 days because i summited at Friday afternoon.

Comment: It would be great if you can add a link from Instagram which advocates your stand.

Comment: I'm sorry, there isn't official declaration of Instagram about that. I had experienced the same situation and those thing are totally my experiences. Each case i had tried no less than twice.

Answer (score 1):

It's been 1 month and still pending review.

Comment: I know that they had suspended this for a while, but is there any where we can look to see when/if they'll start reviewing applications again?